Text positioned over WebGL canvas becomes blurry
I have encountered a problem where my pixelated text that overlaps with a WebGL canvas becomes noticeably blurry. Pictured is (1) the element slightly above the canvas and then (2) touching the canvas (the darker inlay).


I have made a simple codepen example here, tested on Google Chrome: https://codepen.io/sndyx/pen/zxOojwN
This doesn't seem to be affected by any properties such as text-rendering, -webkit-font-smoothing, font-weight, font-size, etc. I have tried isolating stacking contexts of the canvas and text but it seems to have no effect.
Does anybody know how to prevent this?

I have tried your codepen on Edge/Chrome and FF on WIndows11 and Safari on IOS18,1 and I cannot see a difference in the texts whether over the canvas(es) or not. What OS and version are you running on and what device?

It is blurry for me on Chrome (131.0.6778.140) and Edge (131.0.2903.99) on Windows 11. It appears not to be a problem on Safari on either MacOS or iOS. I'm not sure what other variables could be affecting the result, but I will say that the effect can be quite subtle if the text is small.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

@Sandy your font-family is silkscreen which is a pixelated font. did you ever consider changing it? sometimes adding a text-shadow will remedy this kind of issue when using a pixelated font.

I believe what you are looking for is:
document.getElementById("canvas-webgl").getContext("webgl", { antialias: false });


This doesn't appear to have any effect. At least for me, the text remains blurry regardless of antialiasing on the webgl canvas.
